# Complex Fourier series of $ f=|2t|$ in domain $[-1,1]$

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, fourier-series

$
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
 |t|&\text{if}\, -1 \leq t \leq 1\\
 &\text{continue periodically}
\end{cases}
$

I need to find the complex Fourier series (so using the $f(t) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha_n \cdot e^{i \cdot n \cdot \omega \cdot t}$ formula).

Firstly I need to find $\alpha_n$

lets say $i \cdot n \cdot \omega = k$
\begin{align}
\alpha_n
&=\frac{1}{T}\int\limits_{-1}^{1}f(t) \cdot e^{-k \cdot t}dt \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-1}^{ 0}-2t \cdot e^{-k \cdot t}dt + \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{ 0}^{ 1} 2t \cdot e^{-k \cdot t}dt \\
&=\int\limits_{-1}^{ 0} -t \cdot e^{-k \cdot t}dt +\int\limits_{ 0}^{ 1} t \cdot e^{-k \cdot t}dt \\
&=\left[\frac{(k\cdot t+1)\cdot e^{-k \cdot t}}{k^2}\right]_{-1}^{0} +\left[-\frac{(k\cdot t+1)\cdot e^{-k \cdot t}}{k^2}\right]_{0}^{1} \\
&=\left[\frac{(k-1)\cdot e^{-k}}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^2}\right] +\left[\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{(k+1)e^{-k}}{k^2}\right]\\
&= \frac{(k-1)\cdot e^{k}}{k^2}-\frac{(k+1) \cdot e^{-k}}{k^2}+\frac{2}{k^2}\\
&= \frac{e^{k} \cdot (1-k) - e^{-k} \cdot (1+k)+2}{k^2}
\end{align}

Now I can say that $\omega = \frac{2 \pi}{T} = \pi$ this makes $k = i \cdot n \cdot \pi$

$$
\alpha_n= \frac{e^{i \cdot n \cdot \pi} \cdot (1-i \cdot n \cdot \pi) + e^{-i \cdot n \cdot \pi} \cdot (1+i \cdot n \cdot \pi)+2}{(i \cdot n \cdot \pi)^2}
$$

Is there a way to write this better? Is this correct so far?

I think I made a mistake cause when $n=0$ this would mean $\alpha_n= \infty$

Comment: What's tthe relation between $x$ and $t$?

Comment: sorry x should be t

Comment: for simplification let $inw=k$. this makes your calculation simpler.

Comment: yes i did exactly that on paper

Comment: also with $t=-u$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-1}^{ 0}-2t \cdot e^{-i \cdot n \cdot \omega \cdot t}dt + \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{ 0}^{ 1} 2t \cdot e^{-i \cdot n \cdot \omega \cdot t}dt \\
\int\limits_{ 0}^{ 1} u \cdot e^{i \cdot n \cdot \omega \cdot t}dt + \int\limits_{ 0}^{ 1} u \cdot e^{-i \cdot n \cdot \omega \cdot t}dt\\
=\int\limits_{ 0}^{ 1} u \cdot \cos(n \cdot \omega \cdot t)dt=2\dfrac{(-1)+(-1)^n}{n^2w^2}$$

Comment: now that t=-u doesn't make sense 
I changed that original post so it works with k,

Comment: now $e^{in\pi}=e^{-in\pi}=(-1)^n$ for integer $n$.

Comment: Why is $e^{in\pi}=e^{-in\pi}$

Comment: Oh I understand Because n is every real number

Comment: @nosrati thank you very much for beeing so patient

Comment: you are welcome! $:)$

Comment: Nosrati today you're my savior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For coefficients with $\ell=1$ we have
$$c_n=\dfrac{1}{2\ell}\int_{-\ell}^{\ell}f(t)e^{-int\pi/\ell}\ dt=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\int_{-1}^{0}-te^{-int\pi}\ dt + \int_{0}^{1}te^{-int\pi}\ dt\right)=2\dfrac{(-1)+(-1)^n}{n^2\pi^2}$$
therefore
$$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{in\pi t/\ell}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)+(-1)^n}{n^2\pi^2}e^{in\pi t}$$

Comment: I don't get how you get to 1/2*exp(-i*n*pi)

Comment: it's a simple integration by parts.

Comment: $$\int xe^{kx}\ dx=e^{kx}\dfrac{kx-1}{k^2}$$

Comment: yes as you can see i did that too but i became a very different result

Comment: i added some details to my method can you point out where I am wrong?

Comment: I think it's better to do it again. some minus was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean $ f(t) = |2t|$.

The correct answer is

$$f(t) \sim 1 - \frac{8}{ { \pi }^2 } \sum_{ n = - \infty }^{ \infty} \frac{ \exp( (2n +1)i \pi t) }{ (2n+1)^2 }  $$

Your answer is mostly correct. Just note that the even terms are identically $ 0 $ and you can separate your value for $ \alpha_n$ into a sum over negative and positive $n$ .

Comment: how do you get to this result?